# Does the camera on the iPhone 6 protrude from the back?

Tags: hardware, camera, iphone

When the iPhone 6 was announced last week, I read that the camera would protrude from the back of the phone, instead of being completely flush with the back like on all previous iPhones.  Is this true?

On the [Apple web site](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/), you can see the [following image](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/overview/images/design_details_right_large.jpg) showing side views of the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, and neither one shows a protruding camera.

[image]

Comment: You already have the answer !

Comment: I'm going to reverse the closure here. The phone is available for order, so questions on case design and external design are very answerable for the iPhone 6. See [meta] for a discussion on widening the pre-release prohibition on products and services.

Comment: Every single picture I see on https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/cameras/ shows a protruding camera lens but I'm not sure what practical issue you are facing. Are you trying to decide to order a 6 or 6 plus?

Comment: Thanks for that link.  Yes I am wondering if I should get the 6 or 6 Plus.  Interesting how the side view photo I posted doesn't show the camera.

Comment: Apple photoshops all the store "hero" photos and it's not unheard of to edit things. Clearly one of the cameras protrude, so having neither phone show it lets you know they are showing the thin-ness and not the "bump"

Answer (score 3):

Actually according to this photo from Apple web site it is protruding (if you want to call it that way)

[image: iPhone 6 camera]

Due to the perspective- view, it does not show on your pics.

Comment: Also this image from the keynote - http://daringfireball.net/misc/2014/09/camera-bulge.jpg

Comment: @bmike Good one.  I think that proves the image I posted was photoshopped to remove the bulge, rather than it being hidden by the perspective.